# Extremely low p-values from non-parametric tests

Tags: python, scipy, statistics, distribution, kolmogorov-smirnov

I'm using Python's non-parametric tests to check whether two samples are consistent with being drawn from the same underlying parent populations: `scipy.stats.ks_2samp` (2-sample Kolmogorov-Smirnov), `scipy.stats.anderson_ksamp` (Anderson-Darling for k samples), and `scipy.stats.ranksums` (Mann-Whitney-Wilcoxon for 2 samples). My significance threshold to say that two samples are significantly different from each other is p = 0.01.

If these three tests return extremely low p-values (sometimes like 10^-30 or lower), then do I need to worry about something having gone wrong with the scipy functions? Are these ridiculously small p-values reliable, and can I just report p << 0.01 (p much less than my threshold)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not need to worry about something going wrong with the scipy functions.  P values that low just mean that it's really unlikely that your samples have the same parent populations.

That said, if you were not expecting the distributions to be (that) different, now is a good time to make sure you're measuring what you think you're measuring, i.e. you are feeding in the right data to scipy.

Comment: Oh okay thanks! I am expecting my distributions to be different but just wasn't sure if I should trust such extremely small p-values. Do people usually report p << threshold in their manuscripts/publications in such cases?

Comment: Yep, I'd report that p value as p << 0.001 instead of the actual number.

Comment: If this helped, you should be able to click the green check mark by the answer in order to mark it as accepted.  Good luck with your project!

Comment: Wow, thanks a lot -- not sure how I missed the green check!

Comment: @Everyone_Else "P values that low just mean that it's really unlikely that your samples have the same parent populations." -- that's incorrect, a p-value doesn't say anything about the probability of the null hypothesis, although it is a very common misinterpretation.

Comment: @Robert Dodier " a p-value doesn't say anything about the probability of the null hypothesis" - this is not true at all.  It strictly tells you that the probability you received the result you did, assuming the null hypothesis is true is likely/unlikely.  Lower p-values, particularly as low as OP received DO tell you that the probability of the null hypothesis being correct is very low via conditional probability, or, at the very least, much lower than had OP received a far higher p-value.

Comment: That interpretation, which is essentially a Bayesian interpretation, is not consistent with the theory by which significance tests are constructed. For more on this topic, a web search for "misinterpretation of p-values" or "misinterpretation of significance tests" brings up a lot of articles.

Answer (score 2):

A common mistake (at least in life sciences) that can lead to incorrect (too small) p-values is that the **independence assumption** of the test -- tests typically assume that the observations (data points) in the sample are independent -- is violated.  GraphPad's [checklist](http://www.graphpad.com/guides/prism/7/statistics/index.htm?stat_checklist_mannwhitney.htm) for Mann-Whitney, e.g., has this under "errors independent."

As a reference, [this 2010 paper](http://bmcneurosci.biomedcentral.com/articles/10.1186/1471-2202-11-5) looked at a single issue of Nature Neuroscience (a top journal in neuroscience) and found that "12% of papers had pseudoreplication and a further 36% were suspected of having pseudoreplication."

Answer (score 0):

Well, you've bumped into a well-known feature of significance tests, which is that the p-value typically goes to zero as the sample size increases without bound. If the null hypothesis is false (which can often be established a priori), then you can get as small a p-value as you wish, just by increasing the sample size.

My advice is to think about what practical difference it makes that the distributions differ. Try to quantify that in terms of cost, either real (dollars) or abstract. Then devise a measurement for that.